# What are my next steps on finding the cause of this exception?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I'm fairly new to Eclipse, Java, and Android programming. I've taken over development of an Android application. Someone has made a change several months ago that is causing the application to crash (exception) in code that is not part of the application code. I don't have any idea where or what part of the project was changed to cause the crash. I step through the code as the application is running on the Android device but the exception occurs in code that is not part of the application and for which I do not have the source.

I am looking for next steps to help resolve this issue. What are some things I can do?

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception UnsupportedOperationException)) 
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 616  
Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) line: 583  
Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() line: 799 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733   
Choreographer$FrameHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 95   
Looper.loop() line: 146 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5756    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1291 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 1107    
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  


Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception UnsupportedOperationException)) 
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1297 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 1107    
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: "I am looking for next steps to help resolve this issue. What are some things I can do?" -- first, stop your IDE from breaking on the exception. Or, continue past the breakpoint, so you get the real stack trace in LogCat.

Comment: What is the last line in the stack trace (toward the top) that includes code you control? That is usually the best place to start, and understand what objects you are passing along to 3rd party methods.

Comment: [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) ftw

Comment: are you using a version control system? You can compare versions to find what change has been made and where.

Comment: I am using a version control system. There are many files that were changed, including the project layout. I compared two files that I thought might be causing the issue so I used a version of the files from the build that works and I still get the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I step through the code as the application is running on the Android device but the exception occurs in code that is not part of the application

As you've done, step through your application code line by line in a debugger, until you get to the last line which runs before the exception is thrown.

On this line, you'll find a call to some external library. You've said you don't have the source for this library. That's unfortunate, but it's not the end of the road.

The simplest next steps come from realising that your exception is most probably caused by one of two things:

1) You're using the external library in a way it wasn't designed to be used. For example, feeding it some bad data, using its functionality out of sequence, or just in the wrong way. Read the documentation and try to understand if this is the problem. If there is no documentation, well.. welcome to hell.

2) Your call to the external library obeys its contract and is correct. If that's the case, there may be a bug in the library itself. Depending on the library, consult the documentation or any online community sites to verify if that specific bug is known, if there's a workaround, or if you're stuck.

Find out which of these two things it is, then make a decision on how to move on. It might be changing your code, it might be changing the library you use, it might be some combination of the two. Without any more details it's impossible to say. Good luck!